# Mcafee blocks Tcp connection

Tags: .net, networking, tcp, antivirus, mcafee

I am using System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect to connect a remote server.

I see that the call succeeds on most of the systems, but fails on a few.

I tried to debug the issue and observe that system which have McAfee Antivirus installed have the issue. Connection succeeds, if I disable 'Access protection' feature in the Virus scan console of McAfee.

But as per the client policy, I cannot disable the 'Access protection' feature of McAfee. As per them, they are able to run **other programs** which does TCP socket connection with other servers.

What might be wrong specific to my application? Is there a way to specify to bypass blocking of my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your antivirus is blocking your application. If you want to specifically allow you application. follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**
In McAfee antivirus folder from **start button** go to **virusscan console**.

**Step 2:**
Double click on **access protection** from virusscan console.
Now select on **Ant-virus standard protection**. From the window right to it select **Prevent IRC Communication** and click **Edit**.

**Step 3:**
A new window will be opened. In that there is an field to enter **Processes to Exclude**. Enter your **exe file name**. eg: myApplication.exe.
Then click apply this will solve your issue.